# Dropzone specifying a droppable area in form

Tags: dropzone.js

I was wondering if there is a way to specify an area within a form that has been initialzed as a dropzone element.

I have this markup

```
    <form class="vertical-flow vertical-flow--mini" id="new-support-ticket-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        //Have removed all other mark up  for brevity
        <div class="catalogue__upload">
            <div class="file-upload placeholder">
                <label class="is-hidden--text">@BackendText.Global_UploadFiles</label>
                <div class="file-upload__inner" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
                    <div class="file-upload__icon" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
                        <svgicon iconid="page-upload"></svgicon>
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-upload__content">
                        <h3 class="heading heading--quaternary file-upload__heading">@BackendText.Global_DragAndDropFile</h3>
                        <p class="file-upload__sub-heading">
                            @BackendText.Global_Or_Lowercase <label id="file-upload-browse" class="file-upload__label">@BackendText.Global_Browse_Lowercase</label>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="button-group button-group--right">
            <button class="button button--color-orange button--medium" type="submit">Create ticket</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

I create the dropzone programmically via.

```
        var dz = $("#new-support-ticket-form").dropzone({
            // The configuration we've talked about above
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            previewTemplate: '<div style="display:none"></div>',
            url: "@Url.Action("NewTicket")",
            clickable: "#file-upload-browse",

            // The setting up of the dropzone
            init: function() {
                var myDropzone = this;
            }
        });
```

I know the `clickable` option allows to have multiple elements or single one to bring up the file browser. However im wondering if there is a way to specify an element that is the "droppable" for files instead of the whole form. The element I would like is the div with the class `catalogue__upload`

The reason I have the whole form as the dropzone is that I want to upload additional data along with the file(s). The mark up for this is removed for the question, but its basically a bunch of selects and textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using whole form as the dropzone, it would be better to make just the element as dropzone and add additional data to the request using a `sending` event handler.